# downSize image from iPhone while uploading

Tags: iphone

I have an application,
in which

User selects an images from iPhone, for photo field,

Image is uploaded to the server,

Image size may be of 1 kb, or 10 kb or it may be 1 mb or 10 mb.

**If image size is more than 5mb than image must be downsized upto 5mb before storing to the server.Question is How?is it Possible?**

i have used following code for downloading image - for compressing image while loading,
imageDatafromPhoto = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],0.2);

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between 'compressing' and 'resampling'. Compression is a lossless way of making a document smaller, such as GZip. Although there aren't any standard interfaces in Objective-C to help you do this, there's a few extensions for NSData as a category that you can use to add GZip compression.

However, that in itself won't help you. JPEG images tend not to compress well, so what you really want is *resampling* or adjustment of the image itself. This throws some data away, making it smaller but also worse quality. This is the purpose of the 0.2 at the end of it - 0.0 is the maximal compression that you can get out of the library. You could try calling it with ever successively small numbers (say, in a for loop) until you get an image size that is of acceptable quality.

Failing that, you would have to do a resize by drawing the image into a CGContextDrawImage with a specified size into a CG buffer (from CGBitmapContextCreate) and then get the new image from the result drawn in there, and start again.